# How do I combine varying multiple lines of text in Notepad++ into one line of code with a common beginning and ending string?

Tags: notepad++, string, concatenation, combine

I have 1000s of lines of text in Notepad++ with multiple instances of lines beginning with “FIRST_LINE,” followed by varying numbers of lines, and ending with a line called "LAST_LINE,".  While “FIRST_LINE,” and “LAST_LINE,” always appear, there is no standard beginning for the lines in between and no fixed number of in between lines.  For instance, sometimes there are four lines in between, as shown below, other times there are two, etc.

I need a Search and Replace formula to combine “FIRST_LINE,” “LAST_LINE,” and all lines in between into separate lines of text, **so that**:

```
FIRST_LINE, 

second line lfutdytdyt

3rd line x;lkhr;lkj

fourth klufhkgfk

5th ;lkjk;lkj;lj

LAST_LINE,


FIRST_LINE, 

lfutdytdyt

klkrjtlkj

LAST_LINE,
```

**becomes:**

```
FIRST_LINE, second line lfutdytdyt, 3rd line x;lkhr;lkj, fourth klufhkgfk, 5th ;lkjk;lkj;lj, LAST_LINE,

FIRST_LINE, lfutdytdyt, klkrjtlkj, LAST_LINE,
```

(a comma between each former line is preferred but not necessary):

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Comment: Do you **really** have a comma after `FIRST_LINE` and not after other lines?

Comment: Yes.  These lines came out of a long pdf file.  I inserted the commas after FIRST_LINE and LAST_LINE, which are uniform.  The in between lines are long and various.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:((?:FIRST_LINE|LAST_LINE),\h*)|.+)\K\R+(?!FIRST_LINE,\h*)`
- Replace with: `(?1:, )`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                         # non capture group
    (                         # group 1
        (?:                     # non capture group
            FIRST_LINE            # literally
          |                     # OR
            LAST_LINE             # literally
        )                       # end group
        ,                       # a comma
        \h*                     # 0 or more horizontal spaces
    )                         # end group 1
  |                         # OR
    .+                        # 1 or more any character but newline
)                           # end group
\K                          # forget all we have seen until this posiiton
\R+                         # 1 or more any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?!                         # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
    FIRST_LINE,               # literally
    \h*                       # 0 or more horizontal spaces
)                           # end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1         # if group 1 exists (there is FIRST_LINE or LAST_LINE)
                # do nothing
    :       # else
      ,         # add a comma
                # and a space
)           # endif
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your correct answer.  I feel horrible about this because your answer is correct for the exact code I posted.  I negligently forgot to add that while LAST_LINE, is indeed the last line in each record set, there are other lines above FIRST_LINE,.  So, when I run this code, it lumps all lines in the file into one line.  This is my second post and first day on the site.  Should I accept your answer and ask the question again in a different post, correctly formatted, so as to reward you for your effort and not to confuse future readers?  Or do I edit the posted code?

Comment: @mapman: If it's really different, ask a new question with **real test case** an I guess that's the case because if there are other lines before, the answer will be quite different. If it contains minor changes, edit your question and I will modify my answer. Unfortunatly, it's time to sleep here, but if I can, I will reply tomorow.

Comment: I'll go ahead and make a different post.  Thanks so much for your help, I truly appreciate it.  Bon soir.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1594645/how-do-i-combine-lines-of-text-in-notepad-that-are-between-string-lines-into-o