# How do I combine lines of text in Notepad++ that are between string lines into one line of code, while retaining lines outside the string delimiters?

Tags: notepad++, string, concatenation, combine

I have 100s of pages in text format in Notepad++ that came from a pdf file.   Each page in the file has varying amounts of lines, but they all contain lines that read “TARGET_LINE,” and "LAST_LINE,".  Between those two strings are  various lines of text.  While “TARGET_LINE,” and “LAST_LINE,” always appear, the numbers of lines in between differ - sometimes there are four lines in between, as shown below, other times there are two, etc.

I need a Search and Replace formula that 1) retains the lines above TARGET_LINE, but 2) combines all lines in between “TARGET_LINE,” and “LAST_LINE,” into one separate line of code, including the prefix and suffix lines, so that ...

```
abc
123
xyz
TARGET_LINE, 
second line lfutdytdyt
3rd line x;lkhr;lkj
fourth klufhkgfk
5th ;lkjk;lkj;lj
LAST_LINE,
def
456
TARGET_LINE, 
lfutdytdyt
klkrjtlkj
LAST_LINE,
```

,,, becomes:

```
abc
123
xyz
TARGET_LINE, second line lfutdytdyt 3rd line x;lkhr;lkj fourth klufhkgfk 5th ;lkjk;lkj;lj LAST_LINE,
def
456
TARGET_LINE, lfutdytdyt klkrjtlkj LAST_LINE,
```

(a comma between each former line is preferred but not necessary):

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Comment: Hi mapman, this problem is much more harder than the other. I'm trying to find you a solution but it may take a moment ;)

Comment: Thank you, Toto.  No worries.  Don't spend too much time on it because those in between lines will end up as fields in a csv spreadsheet and I can always concatenate them manually there.

Comment: I've just found a solution with a little constraint. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### CAUTION:

#### This will work only if you place the cursor at the beginning of the first line that contains `TARGET_LINE`

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^(TARGET_LINE),\h*|\G)((?:(?!LAST_LINE).)*?)\R`
- Replace with: `$1$2,`
- **UNCHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                     # non capture group            
    ^                       # beginning of line
    (TARGET_LINE)           # group 1
    ,\h*                    # a comma followed by 0 or more horizontal spaces
  |                     # OR
    \G                      # restart fro mlast match position
)                       # end group
(                       # group 2
    (?:                     # non capture group
        (?!LAST_LINE)           # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't "LAST_LINE" after
        .                       # any character but newline
    )*?                     # end group, may appear 0 or more times, not greedy
)                       # end group
\R                      # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
$2          # content of group 2
,           # a comma followed by a space
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Toto, this is brilliant!  Works perfectly.  You saved me hours and hours of time.  Thank you very much for taking the time to help.  Vous êtes très gentil. Merci beaucoup!

Comment: @mapman: You're welcome ;) C'est un plaisir de rendre service.

Comment: Done!  I think, let me know if I didn't  :)

Comment: @mapman: Thanks bro.